# IAM Policy to allow update on a deeply nested attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fine-grained-access-control-for-amazon-dynamodb/) talks about fine-grained column and row level access control with DynamoDB.

However, what if I want to allow a user to UPDATE only a deeply nested attribute inside a column of DynamoDB ?

For eg: I have this object stored in DynamoDB:

```
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Parent_Prop_1": {
    "child_prop_1": {
      "sub_child_prop_1": "some value"
    }
  },
  "Parent_Prop_2": {
    "child_prop_1": {
      "sub_child_prop_1": "other value"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write a policy that allows a certain user to only perform update on this path: `Parent_Prop_1.child_prop_1.sub_child_prop_1` and no other paths ?